# Restriction in Kotlin generic class

Tags: kotlin, covariance

I have:

```
open class Fruit
open class Apple : Fruit()
class SmallApple : Apple()
```

Now I trying to use covariance

```
class FruitBox<out T>(fruit: T)
```

So with "out" in my opinion I should can

```
    val apple2 = FruitBox<Apple>(Apple())
    val apple3 = FruitBox<Apple>(Fruit()) - not compile, - why ?
```

but i can't put `Fruit()` in this Box, why ? Covariance is for class and super class.. 
What is wrong?

How to use out/in for FruitBox only for Apple and super classes ?

Comment: I quess it should be `class FruitBox<T : Fruit>(fruit: T)`

Comment: didn't work also

Comment: What is your use case for constraining the bottom type?

Answer (score 1):

Because the constructor parameter of `FruitBox<T>` must have type `T`, so in particular for `FruitBox<Apple>` it must have type `Apple`. `Fruit()` doesn't have this type.

`out` isn't really relevant here; what it means is that `FruitBox<Apple>` is a subtype of `FruitBox<Fruit>`, so you can do

```
val apple4: FruitBox<Fruit> = apple2
```

> but i want FruitBox only for apple and upper classes (in this case - Fruit) so how to use out/in here

If you mean a specific `FruitBox` value, you can write

```
val apple5: FruitBox<in Apple> = ...
```

and it will compile if `...` has type `FruitBox<Apple>`, `FruitBox<Fruit>`, or `FruitBox<Any>` (and if you remove `out` from `FruitBox`). The problem is there's very little useful you can do with this value.

If you mean *all* `FruitBox` should contain only `Apple` and upper classes:

1. This would be a lower bound, which aren't currently supported in Kotlin;
2. It has a non-obvious effect, namely

   ```
   val apple6 = FruitBox(SmallApple())
   val apple7 = FruitBox("")
   ```

   *would still work*. It's just inferred to be `FruitBox<Apple>` and `FruitBox<Any>` respectively.

Comment: but i want FruitBox only for apple and upper classes (in this case - Fruit) so how to use out/in here ?

Comment: how not supported in kotlin ? from official doc: "Array<in String> corresponds to Java's Array<? super String>"

Comment: Not supported on class/interface and method definitions, only on uses. You don't have an equivalent to `class FruitBox<T super Fruit>`.

Comment: Apparently Java doesn't allow them either, but Scala does.